# AngularJS Form Validation Not Working in Chrome

Tags: validation, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting angularjs form validation to work in Chrome.  [I have a super simple example plunker that illustrates the issue.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ga9arda6vGGUj8OgwmWO?p=preview)  If you enter non-numeric data into the box and click the button, it still says the form is valid in Chrome.  But if you do that in Firefox, it shows it as invalid which is what I would expect.  What's going on here?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug with AngularJS and Chrome, try to add `required` to the `input` and it should work:

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="someNumber" ng-model="someNumber" required />
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ev7s7jX53Y8o2ERh83Ih?p=preview) to test it.

This is the [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2144) on AngularJS.

Comment: FYI - this is not an issue anymore (i know, its an old post, but still figured I'd mention :D)